# Zipping files in PHP without exceeding memory

Tags: php, memory, zip

What I'm trying to do is iterate through a list of links and zip them all into the same directory. The files include images, PDFs, audio, and video. The issue is that some of the files are large and I get the following error:

```
    FatalErrorException: Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 46512453 bytes)...
```

Here's what I have right now:

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
    $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    foreach($mediaFiles as $file){
        $downloadFile = file_get_contents($file);
        $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $downloadFile);
    }

    $zip->close();
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    readfile($tmp_file);
```

Comment: Instead of `addFromString()`, which requires loading the whole file into memory first, try using [addFile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) which doesn't load the whole file into memory

Answer (score 0):

check this library, it allows creating zip files and returns them as a stream:

https://www.phpclasses.org/package/6110-PHP-Create-archives-of-compressed-files-in-ZIP-format.html

Comment: And what does this library do that's different to what the OP is doing with ZipArchive? How will it save memory?

Comment: Basically this library writes the compressed archive to a file instead of a variable when the archive size exceeds a given memory usage threshold.

Comment: You're aware that ZipArchive doesn't build the archive "in memory" either? But it would be more useful for your answer to explain why you make a recommendation for a particular library rather than simply linking to an external site

Comment: yes this library has better features compared to the normal zip function. And this library generates the Zip file in memory (or tempfile) allowing the parent script to save the final Zip file elsewhere, and/or send it to the user.
ZipStream has much of the same features and functions of Zip.php, with a few notable differences, it does not cache and build the zip file on the server, instead it'll send the file to the user as a stream.